# NaN values trying to filter rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting NaN values when I run this code on my dataframe:

```
df['Text'] =df[en_df_low['sent'].str.contains('|'.join(list_1), case=False) & df['sent'].str.contains('|'.join(list_2), case=False)]
```

What this code should do is to assign to a new column, `Text`, value 1 to each row which contains at least one of the words in `list_1` AND at least one of the words in `list_2`; otherwise 0.

This means that if I have.

```
sent

home light sun sunshine  
car park home
home light
sun car park
```

and lists are:

```
list_1=["home", "sun"]
list_2=["light"]
```

I should have

```
sent                          Text

home light sun sunshine        1
car park home                  0
home light                     1
sun car park                   0
```

Unfortunately I am getting:

```
sent                          Text

home light sun sunshine        NaN
car park home                  NaN
home light                     NaN
sun car park                   NaN
```

so something is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is assigned boolean indexing by `df[]`, so it failed. You need assign only masks and convert to `1,0` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
m1 = en_df_low['sent'].str.contains('|'.join(list_1), case=False)
m2 = df['sent'].str.contains('|'.join(list_2), case=False)
df['Text'] = (m1 & m2).view('i1')
print (df)
                      sent  Text
0  home light sun sunshine     1
1            car park home     0
2               home light     1
3             sun car park     0
```

In your solution remove `df[]`:

```
df['Text'] =df[en_df_low['sent'].str.contains('|'.join(list_1), case=False) & df['sent'].str.contains('|'.join(list_2), case=False)]
           ^^^^^^                                                                                                               ^^^^^^
```

to add `().view('i1')`:

```
df['Text'] = (en_df_low['sent'].str.contains('|'.join(list_1), case=False) & df['sent'].str.contains('|'.join(list_2), case=False)).view('i1')
           ^^^^^^                                                                                                               ^^^^^^
```

Comment: it is the same problem I had previously, jezrael. I have a not updated version of pandas so view does not work

Comment: @LucaDiMauro - ya, agree.

Comment: is there any way to fix it without upgrading my version?

Comment: @LucaDiMauro - I think here is problem not in version, but with removing `[]`

Comment: Thanks jezrael. after removing it, it works fine. Thanks a lot